# Image "disappears" under menu

Tags: image, resize

I'm working on a Tictail shop and i have one problem that i just can't get my head around. As you can see here https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXOJf.png, the picture (which is supposed to be on the front page) falls under the menu. I don't know what to do. My first thought was to check the "header", but i couldn't solve it.

```
/* HEADER
**********************************/
#mast {
  position: fixed;<br>
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;<br>
  background: #fff;<br>
  left: 0;<br>
  height: 100%;<br>
  width: 280px;<br>
  z-index: 300;<br>
  text-align: center;<br>
  padding: 50px 0 0 0;<br>
  overflow: auto;<br>
  overflow-x: hidden; }
```

Is it something else i should look for? I also checked the "main-container", but no luck.

```
#main_container {<br>
  margin: 0 auto;<br>
  padding: 80px 0 0 0; }
```

Would be deeply greatful if someone could help me out!

Comment: Nothing happens when i change it.

Comment: I'm just saying, that if you have your menu at z-index 299 (for example), it will end up behind 300, which is where your image is.  So maybe something ELSE needs to have the z-index checked.  LAlso - why do you have "<br>"s in your CSS?  That might be causing it to fail anyway.

Comment: My fault - don't have <br> in the code, just here. Regarding the z-index, i check all off them in the code, nothing happens when i touch them. (Please note that code isn't my strong side..)

Answer (score 0):

I've made it work on my screen using div-tags, but when i test the resolution for smaller screens the picture(s) still disappears under the navigation.

I don't get it. Shouldn't i be able to make the navigation like a 'wall' that the content in the main container can't 'breach'?